# AES256 Decryption Problem

Tags: iphone, aes

I have been using the encryption/decryption as detailed [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html). Following is the scenario :

Retrieved the encrypted data from the server, with utf-8 encoded, xml content.

I am able to decrypt the data to **NSData** format using the decryption method([AES256 Decryption](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html)). But unable to convert the **NSData** hence obtained to **NSString** , by using **NSUTF8/NSASCII** encodings.

*the string to decrypt ,key are as follows:*

**the encryted string:**
****Ti6IFA8agg8XdfYQ/bzpW9OkGM3q3bZMsHrT9lRsg27e8la+GqgE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****

Key:**1ml4nyKW/DggMNhU2qJrvCp80ycHsy32fbSgtdvODGM=**

Note:Iam using ECB mode in the ccdecrypt for decryption.As this mode is used at the server side while encrypting data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you see this - [Convert UTF-8 encoded NSData to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: i used the same approach to convert nsdata to nsstring but iam getting nil response