# NSXMLParser: Unexpected result with non-ASCII characters

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to download data in XML format via a REST web services.
I have already created the parser with NSXMLParser and visualize the data in a TableView.

I have problems when I meet in the XML document sentences with the accent.

Among some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215221/nsxmlparser-cant-parse-special-characters-accents) very similar to my problem and tried to implement it:

```
func parse(handler: () -> Void) {
    self.handler = handler
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        self.countCategoryScheme = 0
        var url = NSURL(string: SomeStructure.firstLink);
        var err:NSError = NSError()
        var dataString: String = String(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
        var data: NSData = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
        let resulset = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(resulset)
        parser.delegate = self;
        parser.parse();
        if !parser.parse() {
            self.delegate?.XMLParserError(self, error: "I Parse Error")
            println("I Parser error")
        }
    }
}
```

in `println (resulset)` I print the entire XML file correctly decoded.

The problem is when I run the parser, the accented characters are not read

This is code when i found Characters in the parser:

```
   func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
        myList[position] = string
    }
```

**EDIT:**

This is an example of my document:

```
<Name xml:lang="en" xmlns="">National Accounts</Name>

<Name xml:lang="it" xmlns="">Contabilità nazionale</Name>
```

In println () print the document correctly as described above.

Instead, when I go to save the data found carachter if "it" saves me this:

"Contabilit"

Comment: Ok i have edited I hope I was more clear :)

Comment: Can you show an example of what you get in String (with reference to the source and what you'd expect)?

Comment: Ok I edited with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parser:foundCharacters:` delegate method can be called more than
once for a single XML element. In your example, it would be called
once with "Contabilit", and once with "à nazionale".

Therefore you have to *concatenate*
the found strings from `didStartElement` until `didEndElement`.

Here is a very simply example how this can be done. Of course it gets
more complicated if you have nested XML elements.

Add a property for the current element string to your class:

```
var currentElement : String?
```

And then implement the delegate methods like this:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    // If a "Name" element started (which you are interested in), set
    // currentElement to an empty string, so that the found characters
    // can be collected. Otherwise set it to nil.
    if elementName == "Name" {
        currentElement = ""
    } else {
        currentElement = nil
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    // If the "Name" element ended, get the collected string and
    // append it to your list.
    if elementName == "Name" {
        if let name = currentElement {
            println(name)
            myList.append(name)
        }
    }
    currentElement = nil
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {

    // If currentElement is not nil, append the found characters to it:
    currentElement? += string ?? ""
}
```

Comment: wow thanks!
But I did not understand why it works. I do not understand because it breaks the phrase into two parts