# How is my array count 0?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray, uipickerview, nsxmlparser

I have a UIPickerView. I have a blank array set up until my code parses an XML request. So when it does I want it to populate the array with that data. Below is how I have everything set up.

```
var pickerData = []

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[row] as String
    }

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
        if (seperatedSoap == "pickerDataString") {
            if (currentElementName == "name") {
                pickerData = [string]
                println(pickerData)
            }

        }
```

I obviously didn't paste every bit of code but you should be able to understand what's going on here. Now my console prints this as my pickerData after parsing.

```
(
    "2x1 on recv-small"
)
(
    "2x1 on ship-small"
)
(
    "3x2 on avs-1"
)
(
    "2.25x2 on photo-large"
)
(
    "2.25x2 on recv-large"
)
(
    "2.25x2 on repair-large"
)
(
    "2x3 on wireless-1"
)
(
    "4x6 on ship-shiplbl"
)
(
    "4x6 on recv-shiplbl"
)
(
    "4x6 on wireless-shiplbl"
)
```

Which is exactly what I want but it's not showing up in my UIPickerView because apparently it's blank? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to use  append to add an element to your array not an equal sign

Comment: Cross-posting :-) I also mentioned that in my answer, but now I think that the count should be 1 and not 0 finally :-?

Comment: I left this one for you

Comment: @TomasKilian's answer solves your current problem. But you should also refer this qa: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28217011/3804019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use

```
pickerData.append(string)
```

since your assignment will always set the array to contain a single (the last) element.

Then you probably need to call `reloadComponent`

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about that! It's been awhile haha, you are awesome! I also changed my array to only accept strings. var pickerData = [String]()

Answer (score 0):

Append arrays  addition assignment operator `(+=)`:

```
pickerData += [string]
```

See [Swift Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)