# How to resolve the Unterminated string around character or invalid string around character from JSON iOS swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xml

I am doing XML parsing and on found character delegate method I get the string value and doing JSON serialisation to get the data. Now for certain search value string is parsed good and I am getting JSON data but for some search string, i am getting an error like Unterminated string around character or invalid string around character.Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

**CONSOLE ERROR:**

```
Started parsing...
[{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Mutiara Damansara","BranchCode":"1064","BranchAddress1":"Lot M2, Mezzanine Floor, Tesco Mutiara Damansara","BranchAddress2":"8, Jalan PJU 7/4, Mutiara Damansara, Petaling Jaya, ","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"47800","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.159858","Longitude":"101.613225","BranchContactNo":"03-77282016","BranchManagerName":"Zainal Jamian","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat10.00pg - 6.00ptgSabtu10.00pg - 6.00ptgSabtu Minggu Pertama11.00pg - 3.00ptg"},{"StateName":"WP KUALA LUMPUR","StateCode":"WPKL","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Mon't Kiara","BranchCode":"5050","BranchAddress1":"E-01-7A, Block E, Plaza Mon't Kiara,","BranchAddress2":"No. 2, Jalan Kiara,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"50480","City":"Kuala Lumpur","Latitude":"3.165294338166839","Longitude":"101.6508936882019","BranchContactNo":"03-62015385","BranchManagerName":"Fazini bt Salleh","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat8.30pg - 5.30ptgSabtu8.30pg - 1.00ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Jalan Semangat","BranchCode":"1012","BranchAddress1":"No.18B,","BranchAddress2":"Seksyen 14/14,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"46100","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.110186","Longitude":"101.636343","BranchContactNo":"03-79562268","BranchManagerName":"Rahimah Bt. Muhamad","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat8.30pg - 5.30ptgSabtu8.30pg - 1.00ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Seksyen 20 Petaling Jaya","BranchCode":"1036","BranchAddress1":"Jalan 20/16A,","BranchAddress2":"Taman Paramount,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"46300","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.107497","Longitude":"101.624303","BranchContactNo":"03-78761494","BranchManagerName":"Zura Syafinash Mohd Amin","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat8.30pg - 5.30ptgSabtu8.30pg - 1.00ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Mini","BranchName":"POS Mini Kampung Chempaka","BranchCode":"PM05985","BranchAddress1":"NO.143 JALAN PJU 1/1","BranchAddress2":"Kampung CHEMPAKA,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"47301","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.116967","Longitude":"101.598338","BranchContactNo":"03-78031646","BranchManagerName":"MOHD NOH LOH BIN ABDULLAH","OperationHours":"Isnin  - Jumaat8.30pg - 4.30ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Seksyen 17 Petaling Jaya","BranchCode":"4640","BranchAddress1":"100-P2.003, The School Blok J Jaya One, No. 72A,","BranchAddress2":"Jalan Universiti, Section 13,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"46200","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.117604","Longitude":"101.634804","BranchContactNo":"03-79574143","BranchManagerName":"Muhamud Fozi Mehat","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat9.30pg - 6.00ptgSabtu9.30pg - 6.00ptg"},{"StateName":"WP KUALA LUMPUR","StateCode":"WPKL","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Taman Tun Dr. Ismail","BranchCode":"6000","BranchAddress1":"Lot 29395
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unterminated string around character 3216." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unterminated string around character 3216.}
&
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
29396, Bangunan Petronas,","BranchAddress2":"Jalan Persiaran Zaaba, Taman Tun Dr. Ismail,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"60000","City":"Kuala Lumpur","Latitude":"3.1421525","Longitude":"101.62518069999999","BranchContactNo":"03-77264026","BranchManagerName":"Zulkafle Harun","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat8.30pg - 5.30ptgSabtu8.30pg - 1.00ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Damansara Jaya","BranchCode":"1050","BranchAddress1":"35, Jalan SS 22/19,","BranchAddress2":"Damansara Jaya,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"47400","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.127831","Longitude":"101.615982","BranchContactNo":"03-77285491","BranchManagerName":"NORMAZNIDAH BINTI MOHD","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat8.30pg - 5.30ptgSabtu8.30pg - 1.00ptg"},{"StateName":"WP KUALA LUMPUR","StateCode":"WPKL","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziBox","BranchName":"POS Laju EziBox @Shell Sri Hartamas","BranchCode":"5053","BranchAddress1":"Off Jalan Bukit Kiara, ","BranchAddress2":"Kuala Lumpur, ","BranchAddress3":"Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur","Postcode":"50480","City":"Kuala Lumpur","Latitude":"3.164073","Longitude":"101.651732","BranchContactNo":"03-22632626","BranchManagerName":"Mohd Tarmizi Bin Ismail","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 Hours"},{"StateName":"WP KUALA LUMPUR","StateCode":"WPKL","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziBox","BranchName":"POS Laju EziBox @PO Universiti Malaya","BranchCode":"5911","BranchAddress1":"PO Universiti Malaya, Dewan Perdana Siswa Jalan Lembah Pantai, ","BranchAddress2":"Kuala Lumpur,","BranchAddress3":"Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur.","Postcode":"59100","City":"Kuala Lumpur","Latitude":"3.149705","Longitude":"101.656163","BranchContactNo":"03-22632626","BranchManagerName":"Mohd Tarmizi Bin Ismail","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 Hours"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziBox","BranchName":"POS Laju EziBox @Tesco Extra Mutiara Damansara","BranchCode":"4783","BranchAddress1":"8, Jalan PJU 7/4, ","BranchAddress2":"Mutiara Damansara, Petaling Jaya, ","BranchAddress3":"Selangor Darul Ehsan","Postcode":"47800","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.159717","Longitude":"101.613137","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 Hours"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziDrop","BranchName":"POS Laju EziDrop @PO Giant Kota Damansara","BranchCode":"4788","BranchAddress1":"Pejabat Pos Giant Kota Damansara, F20
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
&
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
21, ","BranchAddress2":"Tingkat 1, Giant Hypermarket Kota Damansara, ","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor Darul Ehsan","Postcode":"47840","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.156251","Longitude":"101.5944372","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 HoursNext Working Day Delivery Cut Off Time : 4.00pm Monday - Saturday"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziDrop","BranchName":"POS Laju EziDrop @PO Petaling Jaya","BranchCode":"4631","BranchAddress1":"Pejabat Pos Petaling Jaya, Seksyen 20, ","BranchAddress2":"Jalan 20/16A, Taman Paramount, ","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"46300","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.107519","Longitude":"101.6220818","BranchContactNo":"03-79603206","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Shah Redza bin Mohd Radzuan","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 HoursNext Working Day Delivery Cut Off Time : 4.00pm Monday - Saturday"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziDrop","BranchName":"POS Laju EziDrop @PO Damansara Jaya","BranchCode":"4341","BranchAddress1":"Pejabat Pos Damansara Jaya, ","BranchAddress2":"35, Jalan SS 22/19, Damansara Jaya, ","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"47400","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.127863","Longitude":"101.615982","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 HoursNext Working Day Delivery Cut Off Time : 4.00pm Monday - Saturday"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziDrop","BranchName":"POS Laju EziDrop @PO Jalan Semangat","BranchCode":"4613","BranchAddress1":"Pejabat Pos Jalan Semangat, ","BranchAddress2":"No.18B, Jalan 14/14, Seksyen 14,","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"46100","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.1101859","Longitude":"101.6341543","BranchContactNo":"03-79603206","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Shah Redza bin Mohd Radzuan","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 HoursNext Working Day Delivery Cut Off Time : 4.00pm Monday - Saturday"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju Kiosk","BranchName":"POS Laju Kiosk @LRT Kelana Jaya","BranchCode":"4735","BranchAddress1":"K2, Ground Floor, Stesen LRT Kelana Jaya,","BranchAddress2":"Lot. PT 8960 Seksyen SS4, Jalan Lebuhraya Petaling Jaya","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"47301","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.1159087","Longitude":"101.6001339","BranchContactNo":"03-79602806","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Shah Redza bin Mohd Radzuan","OperationHours":"Kaunter PengeposanIsnin-Sabtu                         : 8.00 pg - 8.00 mlmSabtu Minggu Pertama      : 10.00 pg - 3.00 ptg
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
&
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
Ahad"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju Kiosk","BranchName":"POS Laju Kiosk @Encorp Strand Mall","BranchCode":"4779","BranchAddress1":"B-08, Jalan PJU 5/22, Encorp Strand Pusat Perdagangan,","BranchAddress2":"Kota Damansara PJU 5,","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"47810","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.1554957","Longitude":"101.5914995","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Kaunter PengeposanIsnin-Ahad : 10.00 pg - 8.00 mlm"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziBox","BranchName":"POS Laju EziBox @Shell Damansara Jaya","BranchCode":"4742","BranchAddress1":"Jalan SS 24/1, Taman Sea, ","BranchAddress2":"Petaling Jaya, ","BranchAddress3":"Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"47400","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.124047","Longitude":"101.613776","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 Hours"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziDrop","BranchName":"POS Laju EziDrop @PO One Utama","BranchCode":"4790","BranchAddress1":"Lot B21, One Utama Shopping Centre, 1, Persiaran Bandar Utama,","BranchAddress2":"Petaling Jaya,","BranchAddress3":"Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"47800","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.151157","Longitude":"101.614634","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 HoursNext Working Day Delivery Cut Off Time : 4.00pm Monday - Saturday"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"POS Laju EziDrop","BranchName":"POS Laju EziDrop @PO Tesco Mutiara Damansara","BranchCode":"4791","BranchAddress1":"Lot M2, Mezzanine Floor, Tesco Mutiara Damansara, No. 8, Jalan PJU 7/4, ","BranchAddress2":"Mutiara Damansara, Petaling Jaya,","BranchAddress3":"Selangor Darul Ehsan.","Postcode":"47800","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.160082","Longitude":"101.613286","BranchContactNo":"03-61402391","BranchManagerName":"Ahmad Saufi B Taib","OperationHours":"Operating 24/7 HoursNext Working Day Delivery Cut Off Time : 4.00pm Monday - Saturday"},{"StateName":"WP KUALA LUMPUR","StateCode":"WPKL","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat Pos Glo Damansara","BranchCode":"05019","BranchAddress1":"No 3A.03C, Level 3A, Menara Glomac Glomac Damansara, ","BranchAddress2":"Jalan Damansara ","BranchAddress3":" Kuala Lumpur","Postcode":"60000","City":"Kuala Lumpur","Latitude":"3.133852","Longitude":"101.629898","BranchContactNo":"0377314215","BranchManagerName":"Hasnulizam Bin Hassan","OperationHours":"Waktu OperasiIsnin - Ahad10.00 Pagi - 6.00 Ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pos Malaysia The Starling Mall","BranchCode":"05113","BranchAddress1":" Lot G-001, Ground Floor, Pusat Perniagaan Starling Mall @ Uptown,  ","BranchAddress2":"No 6, Jalan SS21/37 Damansara Utama  ","BranchAddress3":"Petaling Jaya, Selangor","Postcode":"47400","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.1352","Longitude":"101.6227","BranchContactNo":"03-77315148","BranchManagerName":"Khairulnizam Abu Kassim","OperationHours":"Waktu OperasiIsnin - Ahad10.00 pagi- 6.00petang( PEJABAT LAMA SS2 PJ)"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS Giant Kota Damansara","BranchCode":"10541105","BranchAddress1":"F 20
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
&
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
21, Tingkat 1,","BranchAddress2":"Giant Hypermarket Kota Damansara,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"47840","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.156251","Longitude":"101.596626","BranchContactNo":"03-61422108","BranchManagerName":"Hasliza Ainun Shaari","OperationHours":"Isnin - Ahad10.00pg - 6.00ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS One Utama Shopping Centre","BranchCode":"1100'","BranchAddress1":"Lot B21,","BranchAddress2":"One Utama Shopping Centre, 1, Persiaran Bandar Utama,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"47800","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.150825","Longitude":"101.614681","BranchContactNo":"03-77279746","BranchManagerName":"NURATIQAH BTE MOHAMED AMIN","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat10.00pg - 6.00ptgSabtu10.00pg - 6.00ptg"},{"StateName":"SELANGOR","StateCode":"B","BusinessType":[],"BranchType":"Pejabat POS","BranchName":"Pejabat POS SEA Park SS2 Petaling Jaya","BranchCode":"1067","BranchAddress1":"No.26,","BranchAddress2":"Jalan SS 3/59E,","BranchAddress3":"","Postcode":"47300","City":"Petaling Jaya","Latitude":"3.110294","Longitude":"101.611860","BranchContactNo":"03-78745866","BranchManagerName":"Khairulnizam Abu Kassim","OperationHours":"Isnin - Jumaat8.30pg - 5.30ptgSabtu8.30pg - 1.00ptg"}]
Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
Ended parsing...
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/28213399/1187415: the “foundCharacters” method can be called more than once for a single XML element, and you have to concatenate the strings *before* decoding JSON.

Comment: Is this the same problem as in your previous questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/56701151/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/56784194/1187415? – As mentioned before, you should show the full XML response.

Comment: @MartinR yes its the same problem. I will edit and show the full response please check. Thanks

Comment: @MartinR I have edited the full response in error console please check.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28217011/1187415 again: You have to concatenate the strings *before* decoding JSON.

Comment: @MartinR I will look into it and get back to you. Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: @MartinR I tried it but still i am getting error. I have shared the complete code over here before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784194/my-json-is-not-getting-parsed-on-some-string-values. Could you please see where i am doing wrong? I have concatenate like  getLocation += foundedChar this in found character. is it right ?

Comment: @MartinR You can please check the currentParsingElement string and getLocation string like how i initiated and get the values