# How to convert NSData to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert UTF-8 encoded NSData to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

I need to to convert the NSData read from file to NSString. How to do it?

Comment: In swift-3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906598/objective-c-convert-nsdata-to-nsstring/40910967#40910967

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`NSString` provides an initializer for this purpose.

```
// NSData *data = [NSData data];
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it this way

```
NSString *yourStr= [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

or the ohther way to use it when the data ends with a null is:-

```
NSString *yourStr= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]];
```

Comment: second option is more elegant and easy to deal with , thanks

Comment: not working for me. data has 4704 bytes when i am using the (either) method suggested by you the NSString is showing nil. Please suggest what to do @roronoa zorro

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```