# Objective-C Convert NSData to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdata

Here are the code I tried to convert NSData to NSString but the program return "Program received signal:SIGABRT".

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
```

OR

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: And if it's not nil, does it actually contain the bytes of a string in UTF-8 encoding? How was the NSData object created?

Comment: @rmaddy While that would result in an undefined string result (almost certainly just a nil return), it wouldn't result in a SIGABRT on that line.

Comment: The data is not nil. There is data in NSData variable.

Answer (score 7):

[Here's a highly up-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring) that shows how to do it.  In a nutshell:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The first idea looks like a fail because of sending `[data bytes]`.  stringWithUTF8String isn't prepared for a void *.  The second idea looks as if it should work, even with nil input.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
NSString* myString;
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

also see this tutorial..

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

:)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift-3**

[image]

**let string = data.base64EncodedString()**

Comment: in your rush to do an "ooh, in swift..." comment, you may want to read the OP's actual question