# How to convert NSData to NSString and revert the NSString to NSData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My task is to encrypt a file(.png, .txt, any..)

In order to achieve it what I doing is

**Encryption:**

1. Read a file and store it into NSData.
2. Convert NSData to NSString.
3. Encrypt the NSString with help of **AESCrypt**
4. Store the NSString in a file

**Decryption**

1. Read the encrypted string
2. Decrypt it with the help of **AESCrypt**
3. Convert it back to NSData
4. Save it back to some location

Below is the code that I am doing in order convert a file to NSString:

```
NSString* sourceFile = @"/Users/Vikas/Desktop/theHulk.png";

NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPat
h:sourceFile];

NSString *dataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Problem:**

The above code is able to read and store the file to NSData however when I am converting the NSData to NSString, the value I am getting is **nil**

**Research**

[StackOver Flow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

[StackOver Flow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565666/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-nsstring/10565711#10565711)

**S.P:** If you have better suggestion for file encryption then please let me know as I am *newbie*.

Comment: Can you encrypt the data without converting to string? Generally, encryption works on bytes, not just strings

Comment: Actually, the library(AESCrypt) I am using is able to encrypt strings so I thought the if I want to encrypt a file then I need to convert it to NSString. It would be great if you could give me a hit about how to en/de-crypt NSData @CarlVeazey

Comment: Dont use that library then. Use common crypto directly or a diff abstraction of it

Comment: @CarlVeazey could you give me a reference link of what you are suggesting. Please do not mind as I have mentioned I am 1-2 month new to this language and cocoa :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579453/nsdata-aes-class-encryption-decryption-in-cocoa got that from searching encrypt nsdata, I believe you may be able to make similar searches to learn more ;)

Comment: Many Thanks @CarlVeazey "Stay Hungry, Stay Foolish"

Comment: Not all data can be converted to any particular string encoding, in particular UTF-8. For tat reason if a string representation is needed the general solution is either to use Base64 or hexadecimal encoding.

Comment: You can use Common Crypto directly but that is not advised unless you are well steeped in cryptography. A better solution is to use a well vetted project such as [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) which also has support for many other languages. RNCryptor handles the necessary details of using AES encryption securely.

Comment: @zaph many thanks :) I'll go through the RNCryptor. God bless you and "Stay hungry, Stay foolish"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/quick-tip-converting-nsstring-to-nsdata/) the string to data conversion forces a trailing `\0` byte, which you might have to remove. This can be done as follows:

`data = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length] - 1)];`

Try see if that works for you.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I am now directly encrypting NSData instead of converting it to NSString first. However, I have tried your way and it is still not working and still NSData is not getting converted to NSString. What's happening: I get NSData of an image in to a NSData variable named "data" then I used your line of code and then I tried to convert it to the NSString however, it is not working and the NSString is still nil.