# how to convert array of objects to json data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I created a custom class for contacts like

```
 *c.h*

 @interface Contact : NSObject

 @property NSString *c_id;
 @property NSString *c_name;
 @property NSString *phn_no;
 @property NSString *email_id;

 -(id) initWithCid: (NSString*) cid andCname: (NSString*) cnm andCphn:(NSString*) ph andCmail: (NSString*) mail;
 @end
```

I am storing them as array of dictionary to convert them to `JSON` data using `NSJSONSerialzation`

I want to know if there is any way that if I am going to create a array of contact objects, how do I convert them to `JSON` data??

Basically my question is how to serialize and deserialize array of objects to and from `JSON` data.

Comment: You need to create Array of dictionary form array of custom objects and then use nsjsonserialzation to convert it to json data.

Comment: This content may be help you [SatakOverflow link][1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932864/how-to-create-json-in-objective-c

Comment: You can traverse each dictionary from your array of dictionary and create Contact object during each iteration, assign appropriate values and add it to some mutable array.