# google places api doesnt give me any results

Tags: ios, json, google-maps

I am building an app that makes use of google places api,i use [this url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.329558,122.025002&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCIZ8MxCoMsfgj0ytE7azXGfjs_E__2Nhw)

the desired link doesnt produce any results when i use it in the browser

and i use json to parse the data coming from google places but i get this unusual warning which says NSString may not respond to JSONValue

the code is as follows

```
-(IBAction)nearbyLocations:(id)sender
{        
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.329558,122.025002&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCIZ8MxCoMsfgj0ytE7azXGfjs_E__2Nhw"];
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    //parse out the json data
    //NSError* error;

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
    NSDictionary* json =[jsonString JSONValue];
    //[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);
}
```

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a larger radius. In the URL you provided, I changed `radius=500` to `radius=5000` and it works. [New URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.329558,122.025002&radius=5000&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCIZ8MxCoMsfgj0ytE7azXGfjs_E__2Nhw). Basically there are no ATMs within 500 meters of that lat/long, but there are ATMs within 5000 meters.

That's one issue. The other issue is in Tsar's comment to your question.