# how to convert NSData to NSString programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

Actually I have an UDPServer app, where i get an ip address as NSData from UDPClient app as response. But i can not convert this into NSString.Please help.

Comment: What encoding is the data in? There is no seamless way to convert data into string unless you know the exact format to expect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //data is your data in NSData format
 NSString *ConvertedSting=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Converted String: %@", ConvertedSting);
```

Comment: i've tried this before. but it's not work for me. thanks for reply.