# Determine if UTF-8 encoded NSData contains a null-terminated string

Tags: ios, objective-c, character-encoding, nsstring, nsdata

I have the NSData-to-NSString conversion in an `NSData` Category, because I'm always using the `NSString` method: `initWithData:encoding:`. But, according to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467856/1231948, it is not that simple.

So far, I have this method in my `NSData` Category, in an effort to keep consistent with methods in other data objects that return a string from a method with the same name:

```
- (NSString *) stringValue
{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

So far it is successful, but I would like to determine if a string is null-terminated, to decide whether I should use this method instead, also from the answer link:

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
```

How do I determine if UTF-8 encoded `NSData` contains a null-terminated string?

---

After getting the answer below, I wrote more thorough implementation for my `NSData` Category method, `stringValue`:

```
- (NSString *) stringValue
{
    //Determine if string is null-terminated
    char lastByte;
    [self getBytes:&lastByte range:NSMakeRange([self length]-1, 1)];

    NSString *str;

    if (lastByte == 0x0) {
        //string is null-terminated
        str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self bytes]];
    } else {
        //string is not null-terminated
        str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: From where are you getting the data? It should not be variable or a mystery if the data is null-terminated. For example, you apparently have some assurance that it's encoded as UTF-8. Whatever protocol dictates that should also dictate whether it's null-terminated. (If you don't have assurance that it is or is not null-terminated, for example, how can you be sure it's not a sequence of multiple null-terminated strings? Or multiple strings separated by nulls, which is slightly different?)

Comment: I'm not trying to give assurance, but rather generality--I'm trying to build a solution that is robust enough to handle data in a wide array of situations. You're right, I'm limiting to UTF-8 for two reasons--1) UTF-8 is the most widely used character encoding online (over 80%), and is recommended by W3C as the standard encoding for languages such as HTML and XML, 2) since UTF-8 is the standard in most cases, I would want to reserve the handling of other encodings in a separate method that would take an encoding as the second parameter, which is how Java's API was designed in later versions.

Comment: In my experience, data coming from a known source is not guaranteed to be null-terminated. Things happen during transmission and that final 0 may or may not arrive. Good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Null termination literally means that the last byte has a value of zero. It's easy to check for:

```
char lastByte;
[myNSData getBytes:&lastByte range:NSMakeRange([myNSData length]-1, 1)];
if (lastByte == 0x0) {
    // string is null terminated
} else {
    // string is not null terminated
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what you need when you run into trouble converting NSData to NSString. See kennytm's answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring. To summarize: if the NSData is null-terminated use [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]], else use [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].

Answer (score 0):

So you wish to determine whether the last byte of your `NSData` is a null, you know how to get a pointer to all the bytes (`bytes`) and how many there are (`length`).

In C a "pointer to all the bytes" can be used as an array and indexed, so you can get the last byte using:

```
Byte *theBytes = data.bytes;
Byte lastByte = theBytes[bytes.length - 1];
```

If you need to support the null-terminated string being shorter then the full buffer you'll have to scan for it, remembering to stop at the end (so don't use something like `strlen`).

In checking for the null you will get both a pointer to the bytes and the length, given that you might want to use `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` to construct the `NSString` rather than either of the two methods in the question.

HTH