# Swift Cannot Assign to immutable value of type NSData

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, hex, nsdata

I have

`let data = NSData(bytes: &positionValue, length: sizeof(UInt8))`

and

`let dataString=NSString(bytes: &data, length: sizeof(UInt8), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Unfortunately the compiler throws an error at the second line, saying that it can't assign to immutable value of type NSData.  How would I go about converting my original `data` variable to a string with encoding `SUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28522827/2303865

Comment: Leonardo, is there a way to avoid using extensions to implement this solution?  Sorry if that's a dumb question but I'm new to Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
let myTestString = "Hello World"

// converting from string to NSData
if let myStringData = myTestString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

    // converting from NSData to String
    let myStringFromData = String(data: myStringData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo!  This worked for me.  Also, both of you said the same thing but Paul answered later so that's why I chose yours as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve, as it isn't explained what `positionValue` is (it seems to be some byte value).

Regardless, the error message arises from your use of `&` with a constant (created by `let`).  `&` provides an unsafe pointer, which allows manipulation of the memory containing the constant's value, but you can't change a constant, so Swift gives an error message.

If you change the first line to read

```
var data = NSData(bytes: &positionValue, length: sizeof(UInt8))
```

then `data` is no longer a constant, but a variable and you can use `&` with it.

Having said all that, since `data` contains the byte(s) you want to convert to a string you can just say

```
let data = NSData(bytes: &positionValue, length: sizeof(UInt8))
let dataString=NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul!  I appreciate the background explanation!  The code you posted worked for me.