# How to get values out of this id type object in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, oop, object

1. The NSLOG of this object is :

   (entity: Article; id: 0xd000000001440000
    ;
   data: {
       email = "XXX@YYY.com";
       name = "XXX"; })

   I want to get name and email from it.

Comment: You could convert it to NSString and then parse it as such. For conversion check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2467856/653513

Comment: But its of id type not NSData. I must have done this using id type. Any other idea. Thank you

Comment: @user3807662 please read a basic Objective-C tutorial. You don't seem to know what types mean in Objective-C nor how they work.

Comment: Where did this object come from? Is there any documentation you can look at?

Comment: @user3807662: as Steve Ives said: if you can tell some more about this object you can get a more elegant solution. But if in hurry and all you need is find a way to get your data then you can convert it to string using code below (after edit...).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest but most error-prone solution is to try

```
id email = [obj valueForKey:@"email"];
id name = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];
```

However this is error prone. For instance, the email could be a string value, or it could also be a wrapper email object.

If you do not have access to this data in the form of public API, you either need to change the library you are using, or find the method to extract this data properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    id yourObject = ...;

    if ([yourObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)])
    {
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourObject];

        NSString *strRepresentation = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"We have payload: %@",strRepresentation);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

There is another way. According to `NSLog` of your object this should work:

```
NSString *strRepresentation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourObject];
```

And parse...