# Can't convert NSData to NSString when using UIImageJPEGRepresentation()?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am creating a multipart image data upload request.
i am getting NSData from UIImage by UIImageJPEGRepresentation
but when i try to convert the data into string i am getting nil value

i have followed this link to convert NSData to NSString

[Convert UTF-8 encoded NSData to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

here is my code :-

```
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
    [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
    int i =0;
    for (UIImage *image in imagesArray) {
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"userfile[]\"; filename=\"image%d.jpeg\"\r\n",i];
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: image/*\r\n\r\n"];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]; //this variable should not be nil
        [body appendFormat:@"%@",str];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
        i++;
    }
    [body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];

    NSLog(@"bodyData = %@",body);
```

I have checked all the variables and they are correct, and are as follows

(only variable "str" should not be nil.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and finally i am getting the body string as follows :-

**bodyData =**

```
--tqb3fjo6tld9
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="userfile[]"; filename="image0.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/*

(null)
--tqb3fjo6tld9--
```

Comment: You can't directly convert `NSData` to an `NSString` since the data doesn't represent a string. You probably need to convert it to a string using base64 encoding.

Comment: @rmaddy : i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring

Comment: That link has nothing to do with what you need. That was about data containing a UTF-8 encoding string value. Your data isn't an encoded string value, it's image data. HUGE difference. Look at the docs for `NSData` for a way to get a base64 encoded string of the data.

Comment: alternatively you can create request body as mutable data and append it with strings converted to data in the same sequence as you do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is thinking that the JPEG representation of an image is a UTF-8-encoded string. It's not. It's arbitrary binary data. UTF-8 strings aren't arbitrary sequences of bytes; there are rules about what bytes can follow other bytes.

You want to encode your JPEG data as a string suitable for use in an HTTP form submission. One way is to use base64 encoding, like this:

```
    [body appendString:@"Content-Type: image/*\r\n"];
    [body appendString:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"];
    [body appendString:[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions: NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength]];
```

On the other hand, you could use the `binary` encoding and include the raw JPEG data directly. In that case, you would need to change the type of `body` to `NSMutableData` and build it up with different methods, as you cannot append arbitrary binary data to an `NSMutableString`.

#### UPDATE

In Swift, with an `NSMutableString`:

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!
let body = NSMutableString()
body.append("Content-Type: image/*\r\n")
body.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n")
body.append(data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength76Characters))
```

In Swift, with a `String`:

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!
var body = ""
body += "Content-Type: image/*\r\n"
body += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"
body += data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength76Characters)
```

Comment: Hi Rob.  Thanks for that; if you see this, I've been wondering .. now in the era of `Data` rather than `NSData`,  how the heck **do** you "convert" a jpeg representation (as you explain, a binary data) in to UTF-8 string (for use, for example, in a http form) ......... ??!?

Comment: Note that, incredibly confusingly, if you have a `Data` x and you add to x a few strings as utf8 using `append`.  *And then you add a 'real' binary data, such as a jpeg representation* to x - in fact it nils "x" - ouch!

Comment: Indeed I asked this as a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808693/with-data-not-nsdata-in-fact-how-actually-do-you-make-a-utf8-version-of-a-jpe