# Convert UTF-16/32 unicode NSString into UTF16/32Char

Tags: unicode, nsstring, utf-16, utf-32

I've got strings that store UTF-16 and UTF-32 unicode value :

```
NSMutableString *utf16String = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[utf16String setString: @"F000"]; //U+F000

NSMutableString *utf32String = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[utf32String setString: @"F0000"]; //U+F0000
```

I want to convert these strings into UTF16Char and UTF32Char in hexadecimal value to obtain the same result as :

```
UTF16Char utf16Char = 0xF000;
UTF32Char utf32Char = 0xF0000;
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTF-8 encoded NSData to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. I want NSString to UTF16Char, not NSData to NSString.