# How to convert String with decimal code characters to UTF-8 String in Swift?

Tags: swift, utf-8

```
let brokenString = "Vatanım Sensin 12. B&#246;l&#252;m Fragmanı yayında!"
```

This is an example of string with decimal code characters.

```
&#246; is equal to character 'ö'

&#252; is equal to character 'ü'
```

How do I convert that string to: "Vatanım Sensin 12. Bölüm Fragmanı yayında!"

Edit: I also have same problem in Android, so added java tag.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will work:

```
- (NSString *) format: (NSString *)string {
     NSAttributedString *formattedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
     return formattedString.string;
}
```

source: [here](https://gist.github.com/asimpson/4de93d0f64bd8953b506)

Comment: I'm afraid that the only advantage of this solution is that it's a one-liner. There are other solutions on SO, give them a try.