# Adding object into NSMutableArray , crashing the App

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Dict is coming from notification, taking out the NSData from dict and adding it to NSMutableArray is crashing the application.

Once in a while this crash is happening not always.

Comment: why dont you convert the NSdata into string in a btter way ? Casting Nsdata into Nsstring is not the right way to do !

Comment: @TejaNandamuri is right you should use `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: @Mridul add your original code here instead of image, just edit.

Comment: The reason of your crash is `self.RFTagData` make sure it is `strong`.

Comment: The code doesn't appear able to crash on the line highlighted, but there it is in the image.  I think better guess is along the lines of threading.  Certainly, preforming the table update on a notification (which may not have been posted on the main thread is crash-ably dangerous).

Comment: @Mridul Gupta why aren't you adding the object as NSData?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the data to array there is no need to cast.

```
if(self.RFTagData != nil){
    self.RFTagData = [dict objectForKey:@"obj"];
}

NSLog(@"array %@", RFTagData);
```

This will add all data to array under the `obj` key.

**Update:**

As user rmaddy & danh suggested, so here needs to take concern over this point regarding use of `valueForKey` and `objectForKey` methods and `nil check on the array`.

**`objectForKey`**: This is an `NSDictionary` method. An NSDictionary is a collection class similar to an `NSArray` (collections), except instead of using indexes like `NSArray`, it uses keys to differentiate between items. A key is an arbitrary string you provide. No two objects can have the same key (just as no two objects in an `NSArray` can have the same index).

**`valueForKey`**: This is a KVC method. It works with ANY class. valueForKey: allows you to access a property using a string for its name.

*Here both returns the value associated with a given key, so here using `valueForKey` method provides workaround solution to you.* But using `objectForKey` is the more preferred way to use in such cases.

---

To check for the `null` values inside array which are identically appears like literals `@"<null>"` rather then `NSNull` objects typically used to represent `nil`s in Cocoa collections. You can filter them out by using `NSArray's` `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` method:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id value, NSDictionary *unused) {
   return ![str isEqualToString:@"<null>"];
}];

NSArray *filteredAry = [self.RFTagData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSLog(@"array with non null vals %@", filteredAry);
```

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`? Don't use KVC unless there is a clear, specific reason to use it.

Comment: Also, you're suggesting that the OP *assign* the array, not add to it?  Also, the nil check on the array is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but it is not solving crash

Comment: @rmaddy regards, for your useful concern kindly check the updated ans thanks.

Comment: @danh regards, for your useful concern kindly check the updated ans thanks.

Comment: @MridulGupta i assume you are getting crash just because of getting null, now please check my updated ans and as i already pointed this please post original code not as image.

Answer (score 0):

NSData *data=[dict objectForKey:@"obj"];
[self.RFTagData addObject:data];

You can directly add data object by doing this.Instead of converting to string.

Comment: The OP is incorrectly casting to a string, but that alone will not cause a crash.  In fact, the cast does nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but it is not solving crash

Answer (score 0):

Don't type cast NSData to NSString when adding objects into array.You should first convert NSData into NSString then add it to array.So
better way to use this NSData into NSString and add NSString into array.

```
NSData *data=[dict objectForKey:@"obj"];
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if(data != nil self.RFTagData != nil)
{
   [self.RFTagData addObject:strData];
   .....
}
```

[Example for Converting Data into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: This, like the others on the subject of casting, is correct, but not an answer to the question insofar as it suggests no cause or remedy to the crash

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but it is not solving crash

Comment: Once you convert the data into string and add it to array then tell me.Also show your code.I will help you.