# Can the conversion of a String to Data with UTF-8 encoding ever fail?

Tags: swift, string, encoding, utf-8

In order to convert a `String` instance to a `Data` instance in Swift you can use `data(using:allowLossyConversion:)`, which returns an optional `Data` instance.

Can the return value of this function ever be `nil` if the encoding is UTF-8 (`String.Encoding.utf8`)?

If the return value cannot be `nil` it would be safe to always force-unwrap such a conversion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522827/2303865

Answer (score 39, accepted):

UTF-8 can represent all valid Unicode code points, therefore a conversion
of a Swift string to UTF-8 data cannot fail.

The forced unwrap in

```
let string = "some string .."
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
```

is safe.

The same would be true for `.utf16` or `.utf32`, but not for 
encodings which represent only a restricted character set,
such as `.ascii` or `.isoLatin1`.

You can alternatively use the `.utf8` view of a string to create UTF-8 data,
avoiding the forced unwrap:

```
let string = "some string .."
let data = Data(string.utf8)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Data(string.utf8)` – I missed that. `.nonLossyASCII` should also work, as it converts unicode characters to their escape sequence, e.g., `"ö".data(using: .nonLossyASCII)` = `\366`.

Comment: How would I convert data to string

Comment: let newString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!

Comment: @AbuTaareq: A conversion from data to string can fail, so it would be `if let newString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { ... }`