# Convert Data to DispatchData in Swift 4

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift4

I am migrating a project to Swift 4 and I cannot figure out how I am supposed to use the new API:s to do this in Swift 4. The following code is the old Swift 3 way (from the middle of a function hence the guard):

```
let formattedString = "A string"
guard let stringData: Data = formattedString.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
let data: DispatchData = [UInt8](stringData).withUnsafeBufferPointer { (bufferPointer) in
    return DispatchData(bytes: bufferPointer)
}
```

Now it gives the following warning: `init(bytes:)' is deprecated: Use init(bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) instead`

In order to do that you need to get access to a variable with the type `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` instead of `UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `withUnsafeBytes` to get an `UnsafeRawPointer` to the data bytes,
create an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` from that pointer and the count,
and pass it to the `DispatchData` constructor:

```
let formattedString = "A string"
let stringData = formattedString.data(using: .utf8)! // Cannot fail!

let data = stringData.withUnsafeBytes {
    DispatchData(bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: $0, count: stringData.count))
}
```

Alternatively, create an array from the Strings UTF-8 view and
use `withUnsafeBytes` to get an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` 
representing the arrays contiguous element storage:

```
let formattedString = "A string"
let data = Array(formattedString.utf8).withUnsafeBytes {
    DispatchData(bytes: $0)
}
```

Comment: Can `formattedString.data(using: .utf8)!` fail with some other string? The string in my project is not a literal. Just posted it that way to make the code shorter.

Comment: @Alex: No. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152617/can-the-conversion-of-a-string-to-data-with-utf-8-encoding-ever-fail.

Comment: OK, nice to know. Also your code seems to give the same deprecation warning. But that is expected since we initialize the type `UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>`, we need something of type `UnsafeBufferPointer`.

Comment: @Alex: That is strange. The code compiles and runs without warnings in my Xcode 9.0 (9A235).

Comment: Site says: Error communicating with database. Snapshot not loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155011/discussion-between-martin-r-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

All solutions above look over complicated, it's actually much simpler:

```
let string = "str"
if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
  let dispatchData = data.withUnsafeBytes { DispatchData(bytes: $0) }
}
```