# Delegating to another initializer from a closure

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm looking at ways to create a `DispatchData` instance out of a `Data` instance. I started with a static function:

```
static func dispatchData(fromData data: Data) -> DispatchData {
    return data.withUnsafeBytes { (typedPtr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> DispatchData in
        let bufferPtr = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: UnsafeRawPointer(typedPtr), count: data.count)
        return DispatchData(bytes: bufferPtr)
    }
}
```

This works fine (and is coincidentally very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46346598/1292061)). I then decided I'd like to add this as an initializer to `DispatchData` in an extension and wrote:

```
private extension DispatchData {
    init(data: Data) {
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (typedPtr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in  // 1
            let bufferPtr = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: UnsafeRawPointer(typedPtr), count: data.count)
            self.init(bytes: bufferPtr)
        }
    }
}
```

At this, the compiler balked on the line marked `// 1`:

> Variable 'self.__wrapped' captured by a closure before being initialized

It makes sense — the compiler doesn't want `self` to be captured before I've delegated to `init(bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer)`, since stored variables — like `__wrapped`, in this case — aren't yet initialized. But I can't see another way to get the `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`; I can't return it from `data.withUnsafeBytes`, per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes):

> **Warning**
>
> The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure.

I know I can just go back to using a static function to achieve what I want, but I'd prefer it if there were a way to add this initializer. Is there a way to make this initializer work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your extension is that although the compiler knows you're passing the closure as non-escaping argument to `withUnsafeBytes(_:)`; it doesn't have any guarantee that it will be called once and *only* once (which is required for initialisation).

One simple solution is to, rather than chain to another initialiser, just construct a new instance of `DispatchData` yourself, and then assign this to `self`, thus completing initialisation:

```
import Foundation

private extension DispatchData {
  init(data: Data) {
    self = data.withUnsafeBytes { (typedPtr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
      DispatchData(bytes:
        UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: typedPtr, count: data.count)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Note also that there's an implicit conversion from `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` to `UnsafeRawPointer?` when passing it as an argument; so we don't need to wrap it in an initialiser call.

And in Swift 5, `withUnsafeBytes` gives you a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` directly:

```
private extension DispatchData {
  init(data: Data) {
    self = data.withUnsafeBytes(DispatchData.init)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, assignment to `self` in the initializer! A good trick, I'll have to remember that. For others' reference, information about implicit casting of between `*Pointer` types can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer).