# dataUsingEncoding failure case

Tags: swift, nsurl

While I usually love my code to succeed, today I need to test it's failure.  Using swift2.3, need a string that I could pass to

```
dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

and have it fail.  I assume it can fail because it returns a optional.

Comment: A conversion to NSUnicodeStringEncoding cannot fail.

Comment: I updated the question.  dataUsingEncoding returns an optional, why would that be if it always succeeds?

Comment: It depends on the encoding, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152617/can-the-conversion-of-a-string-to-data-with-utf-8-encoding-ever-fail. A conversion  to "ISO Latin" or "Mac OS Roman" can fail because those encodings cannot represent all possible Unicode characters.